# Show value from database with dataset in a label

Tags: sql, forms, visual-studio, dataset, label

I would like to show database value in a label.
Now it pops up in a `MessageBox` with the value, but I don't need a `MessageBox`.

```
private void HandleSelect()
{
    string connection =
        "Server = DESKTOP-IRAEU36; Database = Test; Trusted_Connection = True;";
    string sql = txtSql.Text;
    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter adapterSql = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);
        DataSet data = new DataSet();
        adapterSql.Fill(data);
        //dataSQL.DataSource = data.Tables[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            // This is working:
            MessageBox.Show(data.Tables[0].Rows[1][1].ToString());
            // This is not working:
            lbl1.Text.Show(data.Tables[0].Rows[1][1].ToString());
        }
        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        labAusgabe.Text = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
lbl1.Text = data.Tables[0].Rows[1][1].ToString();
```